# Yocto upgrade from fido to morty rootfs is read-only error

Tags: yocto

So, I was given the task to upgrade our yocto based system from fido to morty. I have very little experience with yocto, I have been struggling with it and trying to understand it for almost a week now. I have managed to fix some issues, but now I'm facing a problem when trying to build the image:

```
ERROR: basic-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: The following packages could not be configured offline and rootfs is read-only: ['component']
ERROR: basic-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

If I disable the compoents the basic-image builds just fine, and both of them build just fine on their own, i.e bb component

I don't even know where to start looking for a solution. So if you have any idea what might be causing this or where to start looking for a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.
Ofcourse I have been browsing the yocto manuals, but there is so much stuff that I'm just overwhelmed by all of it.

Comment: Next time, please don't change the question by renaming and removing things after you've got an answer.

Comment: @Anders well, sorry but I just wanted to remove the component names, as these might be considered a security risk, and don't really matter in this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the "problem" stems from the fact that you have the following in your image:

```
IMAGE_FEATURES += "read-only-rootfs"
```

That implies that nothing can modify the rootfs during runtime, everything has to be done off-line, i.e. when constructing the rootfs in question.

Your package `component` (`adcl` and `cfgmgr` in your original question), all have a post-installation script including the following snippet:

```
pkg_postinst_${PN} () {
  if test "x$D" != "x" then
     # Need to run on first boot
     exit 1
  fi
}
```

(Something similar at least, which `exit 1`).

The conditional in my example checks if the `pkg_postinst` script is being run during rootfs creation, if so, it exits with `1` as exit status. That means that the `pkg_postinst` has to be run live on the target system. However, as the target system is `read-only`, this will be impossible, and the build fails.

You'll have to check for `pkg_postinst` scripts, and rewrite them, such that they're able to be run during rootfs creation.

Comment: Do you know if there has happened something between fido and morty versions that might be worth checkning out, regarding to this? Like this: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-2.1-image-generation-split-out-from-filesystem-generation

Comment: No, not that I remember. You might have to show us the `pkg_postinst` scripts in order to track done what's causing this.

Comment: Well, `[ "x$D" != "x" ] && exit 1` is exactly the test I was talking about. The easy changes that would allow you to remove the test is to ensure that all paths are prefixed with `$D/`, as eg `/download` otherwise will refer to your build machine. According to a few emails, even `setcap` should be able to run during either `do_install` or `pkg_postinst`.  Obviously, you can't have a check for eg `/proc/swap`... Hope this gives you some hints.